# compressing multicast packets with zlib library

Tags: c, zlib

I am listening packets from a multicast ip port and trying to compress that packet using zlib library, ( want to know the compression ratio from zlib in the live packets, as this is the requirement from our client). I have implemented zlib compression code as below, but length of `outputDataBuffer` is not printing correct, I dont know what I am missing.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <zlib.h>

using namespace std;
struct sockaddr_in localSock;
struct ip_mreq group;
int maxpacketsize = 1500;

void connectSocket(int &sd,char *multicastIP,int multicastPort,char *interfaceIP);
void listenSocket(int &sd,const short &structureSize,const short &compressionType);
void compressZlib(char *inputDataBuffer,int inputDataLength,z_stream &defstream)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sd = 0;
    char multicastIP[16]="230.0.0.50";
    char interfaceIP[16]="192.168.225.132";
    int multicastPort = 13551;
    short structureSize = 0;
    connectSocket(sd,multicastIP,multicastPort,interfaceIP);
    listenSocket(sd,structureSize);
    return 0;
}

void connectSocket(int &sd,char *multicastIP,int multicastPort,char *interfaceIP)
{
    int reuse = 1;
    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(sd < 0)
    {
        perror("Opening datagram socket error");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Opening datagram socket....OK.\n");
    if(setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Setting SO_REUSEADDR error");
        close(sd);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Setting SO_REUSEADDR...OK.\n");

    memset((char *) &localSock, 0, sizeof(localSock));
    localSock.sin_family = AF_INET;
    localSock.sin_port = htons(multicastPort);
    localSock.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if(bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&localSock, sizeof(localSock)))
    {
        perror("Binding datagram socket error");
        close(sd);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Binding datagram socket...OK.\n");
    group.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(multicastIP);
    group.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr(interfaceIP);
    if(setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char *)&group, sizeof(group)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Adding multicast group error");
        close(sd);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Adding multicast group...OK.\n");
}

void compressZlib(char *inputDataBuffer,int inputDataLength,z_stream &defstream)
{

    char *outputDataBuffer = new char[inputDataLength];
    memset(outputDataBuffer,0,inputDataLength);
    defstream.avail_in = (uInt)strlen(inputDataBuffer)+1;
    defstream.next_in = (Bytef *)inputDataBuffer;
    defstream.avail_out = (uInt)sizeof(outputDataBuffer);
    defstream.next_out = (Bytef *)outputDataBuffer;

   if(deflate(&defstream, Z_FINISH) != Z_OK )
   {
       cout<<"Error"<<endl;
   }   
   //printf("%lu  %lu\n", inputDataLength,defstream.total_in);
   printf("%lu  %lu\n", inputDataLength,strlen(outputDataBuffer));
}

void listenSocket(int &sd,const short &structureSize)
{
    char databuf[5000] = "";
    int receivedBytes = 0;
    z_stream defstream;
    defstream.zalloc = Z_NULL ;
    defstream.zfree = Z_NULL;
    defstream.opaque = Z_NULL;
    deflateInit(&defstream, Z_FULL_FLUSH);
    while(1)
    {
        int socklen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        struct sockaddr_in saddr;
        receivedBytes = recvfrom(sd, databuf, maxpacketsize, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, (socklen_t*)&socklen);
        if(receivedBytes < 0)
        {
            perror("Reading datagram message error");
            close(sd);
            exit(1);
        }
        compressZlib(databuf,receivedBytes,defstream);
        //compressZlib(databuf1,strlen(databuf1));
        //compressZlib();
        //cout<<receivedBytes<<endl;

    }
    deflateEnd(&defstream);
}
```

I also used compress2() function which is as below:

```
compress2((unsigned char*)outputBuffer,&outputDataLength,(const unsigned char*)inputBuffer,(unsigned long)inputBufferLength,Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);
```

but this is also not working, outputDataLength is 0 all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `deflate()` with `Z_FINISH` means that you are or have already fed `deflate` the last of the input data.  `deflate` will then terminate the stream.  Once it has been provided enough output space to write the last of the compressed data, which may very well be on the first such call, `deflate()` will return `Z_STREAM_END`, not `Z_OK`.  Then the `deflate()` engine is done and can't be used again unless you do a `deflateEnd()` followed by a `deflateInit()`, or equivalently and faster, a `deflateReset()`.

It would seem that what you are missing are the rewards that come from having read the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, what I understood is, I have to call deflate() in a loop till Z_STREAM_END, is it so ? and one more thing, why compress2() function is not working..?

Comment: I can't tell what you did wrong with `compress2()`, since you only are showing the call itself.  What is it returning?  In general, you need to _always_ check the return value of functions that return possible error states.